# Trouble retrieving mouse coordinates from canvas

Tags: javascript, mouse, coordinates, mousemove

I'm working on a canvas, and now I've reached the point where I need to find the mouse's coordinates so I can make "buttons" inside said canvas. However, when I try to capture the coordinates and use them in a function to determine if the mouse is inside the button, it doesn't work.

What's wrong with my coordinate retrieval method? This is for a game my friend and I are making for a school project.

Here's the code:

```
<!-- game canvas -->
<canvas id="canvas" width="900" height="600">

<!-- no-support message -->
Se está a ver isto, o seu browser não suporta HTML5.

</canvas>
```

Just the canvas because nohing else really matters.

Here's the javascript:

```
//find mouse coordinates

var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;

$('#canvas').mousemove(function(e){
    mouseX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    mouseY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
});
```

Comment: Could you include your sources or a relevant portion in your question? On Stack Overflow we want questions and answers to be useful in the future even if other sites go away, and your Gists appear to be already gone.

Comment: (I did not downvote this question.) I meant to include the sources in the question, not on an external site like gist.github.com. SO will automatically limit their height, so don't worry about the length (which isn't very much).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var` creates a local variable. In your case, however, you want to update the variables *outside* the function instead of creating new local ones. So, just drop `var` inside the `mousemove` function.

Currently, the outside variables are "shadowed" by the local variables, and have become inaccessible.

http://jsfiddle.net/wXMyH/1/